# Trying to use variables for move-item and receiving error: "unable to bind path"

Tags: powershell, logging, archiving

I am atempting to create a script that zip's up files using 7zip.
I have got the basic's working but after attempting to make it "smarter" i have managed to break it and unable to figure out how to get the new functions working.

```
$filePath = "D:\Logs\test\201310\" #location to look in
$Archive = "D:\Logs\Test\201310\"
$Extension = "*.log" #extensions to look for
$Days = "30" #Number of days past today's date that will be archived
$CutDay = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays($Days)
$log = Get-ChildItem $filePath -include $Extension -recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $CutDay}
$Archivename = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy")
$archivepre = $archive.$Archivename
$Filepre = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $CutDayday}
 foreach ($File in $log)
{
    write-host "File Name : $File " $File.LastWriteTime
}
    foreach ($File in $log)
{   
        if ($filepre -le $filePath)
            {
            mv $_.FullName $archivepre
            }
}
foreach ($file in $archivepre)
{
    $7zipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    $parameter = @('a', '-t7z', '-m0=PPMd',"$sourceFolder$Archivename", "$destinationfolder")
    &$7zipPath @parameter
    break
}
```

The issue i am having is that the `mv` within the if statement is unable to bind the path

```
"Move-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At D:\Logs\test\7zip2.ps1:54 char:7
+                 mv <<<<  $_.FullName $archivepre
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingVa
   lidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,M
   icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

As far as I understand I should be able to set the `MV` to be as is and it should still work?

I want the script to look at the last modified date and only zip up after X days.

Comment: Should it not just be `mv $File.FullName $archivepre`? As defined by your for loop structure. Guessing that it used to be in just a simple `ForEach-Object{}` loop? The statement `if ($filepre -le $filePath)` does not make sense to me since `$filepre` is an array. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: ah thank you, i saw this error before using `mv $File.FullName $archivepre` but can see this is failing for a different error now!, believed it to be the same error previously.

The `$filepre` was meant to get the list of files based on the last modified date which was less than 30 days and compare that to the folder. 
I am attempting for the script to read the files last modified date using that as a bases of which to compress, that part of the script is to move the files as we were having issues with the script just compressing the folder so the idea was to move them to a temp directory.

Comment: Just want to be clear on what you mean by _believed it to be the same error previously_ Are you still getting the same error now? So you are zipping all files in a temporary folder that are no more than 30 days old?

Comment: No, the error itself is now complaining regarding the destination (which i know that setting is wrong, the settings is a reminder of what i am aiming for, create a folder in the archive directory with the archive name.
Correct, that would be the idea of the script as a final product as i couldn't work out how to get it to zip the files in the folder based on the date.

Comment: i think your error relates to the following line, $archivepre = $archive.$Archivename... It should probably read $archivepre = $archive + "\" + $archivename for it to be accepted as a path.